# Arch Linux Ethernet less than 1ko/s

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, ethernet

Since some days, my Ethernet connection is less than 1ko/s, same for Wi-Fi.
Here's enp0s10 (result of `ip addr`):

```
enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether d8:0d:17:e3:52:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.0.15/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s10
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 2a01:e34:efc9:7140:c4b9:236c:db61:b685/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
      valid_lft 86351sec preferred_lft 86351sec
   inet6 2a01:e34:efc9:7140:2af1:2664:9e98:be55/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
      valid_lft 86384sec preferred_lft 86384sec
   inet6 fe80::fd7f:3481:471d:ef3a/64 scope link noprefixroute
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I copied it by hand so I hope I didn't make any mistake..
When I do `ping www.google.fr` I get the following error:

```
ping: www.google.fr: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My DNS servers are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: Try these -- 1. disable IPv6 2. ping default gateway IP address 3. ping DNS IP, if failed change it

Comment: 1. Doesn't change anything 2. `ping -b 192.168.0.254` packets transmitted and received 3. `ping 8.8.8.8` packets transmitted and received

Comment: Seems like the connection is back... I don't know what happened...

Comment: At the moment, it doesn't looks like an Unix/Linux issue but an issue of your ISP. First, try removing your *custom* DNS and report us if problem continues